# Resharper formatting on wrapping long statement

Tags: resharper

It seems like resharper would handle this better, I'm betting I just have the wrong configuration. If you have a line like

```
var products = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Product)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("Category", category)).List<Product>();
```

and you have wrap lines on, it gets reformatted to

```
 var products =
     session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Category", category))
            .List<Product>();
```

Something more like

```
 var products = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product))
                       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Category", category))
                       .List<Product>();
```

Would be preferable. Not a big deal, but I'd thought I'd ask.